# Laravel Null dump value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to find the data coresponding to a specific id, i keep getting this error, i tried dump the id value and it shows `NULL`, no idea why, here is code :

Controller :

```
 function fetchdata(Request $request)
        {
            $id = $request->get('ID');
            $req = Demo::find($id);
            $output = array(
                'reponse'    =>  $req->reponse,
            );
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
```

View :

```
$(document).on('click', '.req_reponse', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("ID");
        $('#form_output').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('admin.fetchdata')}}",
            method:'get',
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#reponse').val(data.reponse);
                $('#ID').val(id);
                $('#studentModal').modal('show');
            }
        })
    });
```

Error :

```
'reponse'    =>  $req->reponse,

    "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting error because there is no key like ***reponse*** in $req variable.

I think this should work fine:

```
$id = $request->ID;
$demo = Demo::find($id);
if (empty($demo)) {
    exit(json_encode(['message' => "not found"])); // Or any thing you want to return if record not found corresponding to given id.
}
$output = array(
    'reponse' => $demo->reponse,
);
echo json_encode($output);
exit;
```

Comment: Please tell me why do i need to add exit ?

Comment: It's recommended to end script and not process further.

Comment: This removed the error message but should i not specify the column name in `'reponse' => $demo,` like `'reponse' => $demo->'reponse',` this will make the error but when doing it like the answer is this not gonna return all collumns inside a single attribute ?

Comment: Can you post the table structure for `demo` and also which column do you want?

Comment: `Demo = ['ID', 'nom', 'prenom', 'reference', 'n_mac', 'n_serie', 'probleme_survenu', 'plus_infos', 'reponse'];` i want column `reponse`

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent doesn't provide such a key `response`. Please try the below script.

```
 function fetchdata(Request $request)
            {
                $id = $request->get('ID');
                $req = Demo::find($id);
                $output = array(
                    'reponse'    =>  $req->your_column_name,
                );
                echo json_encode($output);
                exit;
            }
```